# trying to rearrange data in mysql

Tags: mysql

So my data set has recently outgrown excel, so I have migrated it into a mysql database. Very interesting and all however I'm a bit of a novice at sql and could do with some guidance on how to rearrange data in a a table... The end output will be pulled to a csv and then put into excel which is where all my calculations are done. So this is a very simplified version of the master data which if there is a solution, I can apply to my actual data:

```
+----------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|      KEY       |  Date  |     Name     | Cups of tea |  Shoes   |
+----------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| UniqueString1  | 26-Feb | John Smith   |           2 | Slippers |
| UniqueString2  | 24-Feb | Billy        |           4 | Boots    |
| UniqueString3  | 21-Feb | Joe Bloggs   |           5 | Wellies  |
| UniqueString4  | 20-Feb | Simple Simon |           1 | Slippers |
| UniqueString5  | 18-Feb | Jimbob       |           2 | Boots    |
| UniqueString6  | 15-Feb | John Smith   |           4 | Wellies  |
| UniqueString7  | 12-Feb | Joe Bloggs   |           1 | Slippers |
| UniqueString8  | 11-Feb | Jimbob       |           5 | Boots    |
| UniqueString9  | 09-Feb | John Smith   |           4 | Wellies  |
| UniqueString10 | 08-Feb | John Smith   |           3 | Slippers |
+----------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

Then from this, there is another table, which is what i want to build off:

```
+----------------+--------+------------+
|      KEY       |  Date  |    Name    |
+----------------+--------+------------+
| UniqueStringB1 | 27-Feb | John Smith |
| UniqueStringB2 | 27-Feb | Billy      |
| UniqueStringB3 | 27-Feb | Joe Bloggs |
+----------------+--------+------------+
```

So, what i need from the code is to arrange the first dataset by date, then find the most recent match for 'John Smith', and add to the right the data from this row (date (26/2/2020), cups of tea (2) and shoes (slippers)). Then the 2nd most recent match of 'John Smith' to the right of this (date (15/2/2020), cups of tea (4) and shoes (wellies)). This would continue either until there are no more matches or the the next match is more than 3 years from the date in this table (27/2/2020). So the final table output would be:

```
+--------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+
|  Date  |    Name    |  date  | cups of tea |  shoes   |  date  | cups of tea |  shoes   |  date  | cups of tea |  shoes  |  date  | cups of tea |  shoes   |
+--------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+
| 27-Feb | John Smith | 26-Feb |           2 | slippers | 15-Feb |           4 | wellies  | 09-Feb |           4 | wellies | 08-Feb |           3 | slippers |
| 27-Feb | Billy      | 24-Feb |           4 | boots    |        |             |          |        |             |         |        |             |          |
| 27-Feb | Joe Bloggs | 21-Feb |           5 | wellies  | 12-Feb |           1 | slippers |        |             |         |        |             |          |
+--------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

I appreciate this might not be easy since I'm asking for data from multiple unique keys to be put into one row... If my data needs reentering into mysql in a different way, I can do that too.

Thanks for any help :)

(Just to clarify, all dates in mysql are in the yyyy-mm-dd format with the columns set as 'DATE' data)

Comment: sorry about the data I tried to format it correctly :(

Comment: Those aren't dates. Those are just bits of text that to you look like dates, but to me look like a huge problem waiting to happen. Try and use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default, that is `YYYY-MM-DD`, to avoid ambiguity and to ensure they can be properly sorted.

Comment: sorry i can confirm the dates ARE in the format yyyy-mm-dd and the column is set as DATE

Comment: I think that you have a major problem with how you present the data. What happens if Billy purchases 5 items on one day? Your table will have a "ragged bottom". You should try and keep your data in a tabular format - is what you want easy in Excel?

Comment: I have a vba script which does this however there are 1 million rows of the main dataset and just to run this for 500 rows takes around 10 minutes...

Comment: MySQL, like most SQL databases, is not interested in producing result sets of irregular length. Although that's your desired form, it runs contrary to how an RDBMS is supposed to work. If you need that output form, I'd pull down the relational data, then handle the display logic in your application layer.

Comment: yes i was worried about that... so you are saying, in this example, return all rows for 'john smith' and then rearrange in excel? (sorry i am not used to the lingo haha).

Comment: Perhaps a solution could be to return all the required data into one extra column, comma separated and then put it into excel and use the 'text to columns' function to separate them out? Unfortunately I am looking for a 'jagged' output however an acceptable compromise could be to return the first 50 matches, with anything not found returning null? so there are 150 'set' columns with some rows perhaps being 150 x null and others being fully populated with data depending on how many matching names there are? (hope this makes sense)